# To implement a Shared memory manager in C++

Tags: android, c++, linux, shared-memory

I have implemented a simple shared memeory code which is scattered in the two processes(1 acts writer and other acts as reader). But I want manage this SHM code(just like a memory manager),which works independent of any reader/writer processes. By simply giving some hooks/pointers to out side, Can any one suggests me a way for this. or any related code or links regarding related information to this ? One more this Can I use Zygote process to make it happen please suggest ?

Comment: What is a `Zygote` process? If that is process on a particular operating system, tag your question with appropriate tag for that operating system.

Comment: In fact, please tag your question with either operating system or portable implementation of shared memory you are using, because C++ standard does not provide shared memory implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An application cannot "share" its memory using plain pointers on a modern operating system. This is something which requires the assistance of the OS, and is highly dependent on the OS in question. For instance, on Linux the best bet would be to use SysV Shared Memory.

Make sure you understand the overhead of multiple process shared memory and ask yourself if just using threads would not suffice. In most cases, threads will suffice, or if not you should re-think your model to use a message passing/shared nothing model.

Comment: Yes, It Linux OS related question only. But in my there should two independent processes, among them one acts as daemon to write the data into SHM.but I dont want to keep the SHM code into Daemon.

Comment: I strongly disagree with SysV shared memory. POSIX shared memory (creating a file in /dev/shm, which should be memory-backed filesystem) and mmaping it is the preferred method on Linux. It's simpler interface, lower chance of conflicts (since it's named by string compared to SysV IPC's integer) and you can ensure kernel will clean it up if you unlink the file after opening it (you can't do anything similar for SysV IPC).

Comment: The overhead of POSIX shared memory between processes is very small compared to threads. The only difference is that when switching between processes, page tables need to be reloaded while threads share the same, so it's not needed there. On the other hand, processes are easier to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at what [Boost.Iterprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) can do for you. Especially have a look at the [Managed Memory Segments](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html) section.